# teamcity powershell - unable to run batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, teamcity, start-process

I've spent quite a bit of time banging my head on this one. A little StackOverflow help please, good folks!

**Scenario:** We are trying to run a custom .bat file located on the CI server via the TeamCity Powershell step.

- When powershell script is run on local box manually, it kicks off .bat file correctly.
- When powershell script is run through TeamCity, it successfully 'sees' the .bat file (validated by receiving a 'cannot find file' response when I rename the .bat file it is expecting)
- HOWEVER, we have not seen any indication that the .bat file was actually kicked off.

**What we've tried:**

- We've added the 'RedirectStandardOutput' and 'RedirectStandardError' for attempt to diagnose, but although the log file is created, it is returned blank.
- We've granted filepath permissions and tried two different credentials including the credential of the TC build agent
- Added "-wait" at one point to see if we needed to 'tell' PS to wait on the .bat file.

**Two questions...**

- What is preventing us from running this .bat file?
- How do we diagnose issues like this? ATM it is a 'blackbox' to us.

**TeamCity Powershell settings:**

- Powershell Run Mode: Version 1.0; Bitness x64 (tried x86 as well)
- Working Directory: Tried as blank, and specific filepath of .bat file (so, 'D:\folder\folder2\')
- Script: Source Code
- Script Execution: Execute .ps1 from external file (tried with 'Put script into PowerShell stdin with "-Command -" argument' as well)
- Add -NoProfile argument (tried both)

**Powershell script:**

```
#Predefine necessary information
$Username = "DOMAIN\username"
$Password = "password"
$ComputerName = "CI Build Server Name"

#Create credential object
$SecurePassWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassWord

#Start batch file
Start-Process "testbat.bat" -WorkingDirectory D:\file\path\ -Credential ($Cred)-NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardError stderr.txt -RedirectStandardOutput stdout.txt

Write-Host "Executed powershell."
```

**UPDATE 1**: If we remove the '-Credential ($Cred)' portion we are able to kick off the testbat.bat file from TeamCity, as expected. The problem must lie with that "-Credential ($Cred)" argument, somehow. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 2**: If we set the '-Credential ($Cred)' portion to the credential of the build agent user we are able to kick off the test.bat file from TeamCity. The problem only occurs when we set the credential to a user other than the one running the build agent. This seems to indicate that credential syntax is fine.

**UPDATE 3**: Tried running with PowerShell executionpolicy set to 'RemoteSigned' and 'Unrestricted'. Problem persists.

**UPDATE 4**: Gave the BuildAgent user, and the user of whom we want to run this as, full permissions to powershell via 'Set-PSSessionConfiguration'. Problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential(".\user", (ConvertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -Force))
     Start-Process powershell -Credential $credential -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process  D:\file\path\test.bat -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardError stderr.txt -RedirectStandardOutput stdout.txt }'
```

note:
first i get credential "user" ur user then convert your pass to plain text
then start-process with your credential set

Comment: Hi Soheil, I first tested this syntax change out on my local script and it functioned same as before. I then made the change in my teamcity powershell step and the .bat is still not being kicked off. One difference was with this syntax change 'stderr.txt' and 'stdout.txt' are not being created. Before, they were created empty.

Comment: "echo "%username%" > D:\path\path\log.txt" ; What are your powershell step settings like?

Comment: @ECD your means  `$env:USERNAME > username.txt`  ?

Comment: the .bat file I am trying to call from the powershell script has the syntax "echo "%username%" > D:\path\path\log.txt". It works locally, but does it need to be changed?

Comment: `echo %username% > path` not has problem until when you redirect the output to path with privilege of user does not access to path in destination you run bat do you have access to d:\path ? or not check ntfs permission for write and modify permission on path

Comment: After removing the '$Cred' argument we are able to kick off the testbat.bat from teamcity. It looks like TeamCity has permissions to get to the necessary folder/files. The culprit is with the $Cred argument we are using, somehow...

Comment: I test this script on 2 windows with no problem do you use -WorkingDirectory argument for start-process ? just use full path to script i means d:\path\1.bat ,d:\stderr.txt,d:\stdout.txt

Comment: We have tried with both '-WorkingDirectory' in the Start-Process as well as in the TeamCity Powershell settings. It makes no difference. Additionally, we are able to kick off the .bat file from TeamCity when we drop the $Cred, so this doesn't seem to be a file location problem. The issue is with the $Cred component. It functions fine when run as a local powershell script directly, but does not work when attempted through TeamCity.

Comment: Soheil, do you know of any TeamCity Reps that we could discuss with? This is becoming more of a problem with time.

Comment: @ECD I do not work with teamcity ,i dl teamcity and test my script then Notify to you

Comment: No problem! I just thought I'd check.

Answer (score 0):

If agent is running as service under Local System account, then it's not possible to run PowerShell under specified account. The workarounds are:

1. Run agent via [command line](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-ManualStart).
2. Try to run agent service under another account (not Local System) with administrator rights, probably it will help.
3. Try [RunAs plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-runas-plugin). It provides an ability to run builds under the specified user account.